# How do I create and check if a PDF is in X/1-a format?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've created PDF files with Photoshop, then combined them to create a 16 page PDF. Photoshop's colour profile is set to SWOP (Newsprint), with Total Ink Limit set to 235%.

The file will be printed and needs to be in PDF X/1-a format. Using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, I tried Preflighting the file to get it into the correct format. Sometimes I get a colour warning, mostly I don't. When I tried uploading the preflighted file to the printers site I got the following: "WARNING Your file is not in PDF X/1-a format."

Assuming there is nothing wrong with the website, how can I create and check that my PDF is in the correct format?

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with the website. At least this question should still be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Acrobat:

1. open the pdf you want to check
2. open Print Production tools (View > Tools > Print Production)
3. click Preflight
4. click the PDF/X Compliance tab
5. click 'verify compliance with PDF X/1-a
6. see the report.

If it fails, you can convert it to a PDF/X standard using the selections above 'verify compliance…'. However be cautious of the result. You may not like it depending on how your file was built.